# Regex for an email address doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, email, nspredicate

I'm trying to check if some email address is correct with the following code :

```
NSPredicate *regexMail = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '.*@.*\..*'"];
if([regexMail evaluateWithObject:someMail])
...
```

But the "\." doesn't seem to work since the mail "smith@company" is accepted. Besides, I have the following warning : "Unknown escape sequence"

Edit :

I'm programming in Objective-C for iPhone.

Thanks

Comment: What regex library are you using? Which programming language?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mentionned that xD

It's Objective-C for iPhone programming.

Comment: Apart from the fact that matching an e-mail address with a regex is really difficult, there's no reason why there would have to be a . after the @.  For instance, postmaster@com is probably a valid e-mail address.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot correctly validate an email address with regular expressions alone.  A simple [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=validate+email+address+[regex]) will show you many articles discussing this.  The problem lies with the nature of DNS: there are too many possible domain names (including non-english and Unicode domains), you cannot correctly validate them using a regex.  Don't try.

The only correct way to determine if an email address is valid is to send a message to the address with a unique URL that identifies the account associated with the email, for the user to click.  Anything else will annoy your end-user.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I'm only trying to do a simple check, just to see if the mail looks like "name@company.com" with "@" and "."

Comment: In which case `..*[@]..*[.]..*` should cover your needs.  I use `..*` to match at least one character, because `.+`, while more direct, isn't supported by all RegEx libraries.  I use `[@]` and `[.]` because they will match a single character, without needing to deal with backslashes and double-backslashes for escaping a single character.

Answer (score 13):

This is the regular expression used by the iOS Mail application to validate an email address:

```
^[[:alnum:]!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+((\.?)[[:alnum:]!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@[[:alnum:]-]+(\.[[:alnum:]-]+)*(\.[[:alpha:]]+)+$
```

And here is a copy/paste ready function using this regular expression to validate an email address in Objective-C:

```
BOOL IsValidEmail(NSString *email)
{
    // Regexp from -[NSString(NSEmailAddressString) mf_isLegalEmailAddress] in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework
    NSString *emailRegex = @"^[[:alnum:]!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+((\\.?)[[:alnum:]!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@[[:alnum:]-]+(\\.[[:alnum:]-]+)*(\\.[[:alpha:]]+)+$";
    NSPredicate *emailPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailPredicate evaluateWithObject:email];
}
```

Comment: `john.doe@yahoo` is valid with this one

Comment: Oops, good catch! I forgot to escape `.` with `\.` The regular expression is now fixed.

Comment: I'm very bad at regex, so I was looking for a "ready to use" Regex. But this one (using NSPredicate regex implementation) has a major problem: try to validate this string: @"asdkfjaskdjfakljsdfasdkfjaskdjfakljsdfasdkfjaskdjfakljsdfasdkfjaskdjfakljsdf"and you'll see it never ends.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working example, with a *slightly* more appropriate pattern (although it's not perfect, as others have mentioned):

```
NSString* pattern = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", pattern];
if ([predicate evaluateWithObject:@"johndoe@example.com"] == YES) {
  // Match
} else {
  // No Match
}
```

Comment: Still the same problem here with the caracter "."
"johndoe@example" is matched but it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it should be `\\.`, since `\` itself should be escaped as well.

Comment: Already tried that, the warning disapeared, but the regex didn't work anyway. Will try the regex below. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This page has a good explanation of using regular expressions to validate email, as well as some regexes:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Their expression:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

Seems to be the best tradeoff between thoroughness and correctness.

Comment: This doesn't account for capital letters?

Answer (score 0):

try putting double slash instead of one slash. that's what might the Unknown escape sequence mean.

here is a website that can help you understand how to use regex: http://www.wellho.net/regex/java.html

or just find the appropriate regex for email address here:
http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=0&categoryId=1

Answer (score 0):

I think youre looking for [this](http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php). Its a quite comprehensive listing of different regexps and a list of mail addresses for each, stating if the regexp was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste solution (I added capital letters for the first example):

> We get a more practical implementation of RFC 5322 if we omit the
>   syntax using double quotes and square brackets. It will still match
>   99.99% of all email addresses in actual use today. [Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)
>
> ```
> [a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
> ```

```
  NSString * derivedStandard = @"[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\\.)+[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?";
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", derivedStandard];
  BOOL isValid = [predicate evaluateWithObject:emailAddress];

//doesn't fail on ;)
@"asdkfjaskdjfakljsdfasdkfjaskdjfakljsdfasdkfjaskdjfakljsdfasdkfjaskdjfakljsdf"
```

For those who want to implement full RFC5322

> The official standard is known as RFC 5322. It describes the syntax
>   that valid email addresses must adhere to. You can (but you
>   shouldn't--read on) implement it with this regular expression:
>
> ```
> (?:[a-z0-9!#$%\&'*+/=?\^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%\&'*+/=?\^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
> ```

```
  NSString *rfc5322 = @"(?:[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])";
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", rfc5322];
  BOOL isValid = [predicate evaluateWithObject:emailAddress];
```

Above regexps you can test using online regular expression [tester](https://regex101.com/#pcre)