# Extract emails from string in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, regex

I need to extract emails contained into a NSString like this:

```
This is an email test@test.de and another one is this test2@test.com
```

I read about 2 solutions.. use Regular expression or range but i'm still confused.

Comment: I'm sorry .. writing the title i get from automation only similar argument  that i don't realize were so similar to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are indeed plenty of similar questions on StackOverflow related to usage of **regular expressions** in **Objective C**. See [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex+objective-c), for instance.

However, it looks like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179859/regex-for-an-email-address-doesnt-work), among others, may provide you with some additional help on your email related subject.

Please keep in mind that [there's no perfect simple-silver-bullet-regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses) for parsing emails. It's a tricky business :)