How to save a part of a string that does not have a fixed lenght in objective C?
I have text that has no fixed length, like:
NSString *stringToSplit = @"0.01 EUR sent from sender.email@domain.com. Hi. I'm sending you a free credit. Talk to you.";

I need to save in a string only the part after the “.com. “
The problems are as follows:

stringToSplit does not have a fixed length.
the domain of the internet addresses can vary (.com/.org/.it etc...)

What I tried to do was this:
NSString *stringToSplit = @"0.01 EUR sent from sender.email@domain.com. Hi. I'm sending you a free credit. Talk to you.";

NSArray *firstSeparatedText = [stringToSplit componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];

NSArray *secondSeparatedText = [[firstSeparatedText lastObject] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:secondSeparatedText];

NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
[arr removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexSet];

NSMutableString *textToShow = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (NSObject * obj in arr)
{
    [textToShow appendString:[obj description]];
}

The problem is precisely that using the componentsSeparatedByString: method, the saved text would be

“Hi I'm sending you a free credit Talk to you”

but I need to save the dots as well.
Basically I would like to save only the text that is after the email address (followed by the dot).

Why not use a regexp? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression

So the question is more: Find the email address + dot (optional ?), then from that range, keep only what's after? So this question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413291/extract-emails-from-string-in-objective-c

You can use NSDataDetector

Parsing email addresses correctly is very hard, there are so many edge cases.
As @Cy-4AH suggested NSDataDetector is a better solution. This is a non-trivial problem!
